# Mac OS X bluetooth programming sample?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bluetooth, iobluetooth

I am trying to develop an application using bluetooth in my Mac mini. However, after searching all over net, all that I could find was the "Bluetooth Device Access Guide" from Apple, and not a single sample program!

Can anyone suggest of any sample code for this available ?

**what I am trying to do in my program:**

I want to pair my iPhone with my Mac programmatically over the PAN profile, and then send data (streams) both ways. I paired them manually, and I was successfully able to transfer data. I just want to do that programmatically!

Comment: look at this code =) http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/

Comment: Try [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MoreSCF/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

[In 2016] I suspect you want [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html)

> The Core Bluetooth framework provides the classes needed for your iOS and Mac apps to communicate with devices that are equipped with Bluetooth low energy wireless technology

You can do things like discover paired devices around you, read and write, and it documents best practices!